# Erro em requisição ajax no Node

Tags: ajax, node.js

Eu tenho uma view que contém um form para login. A requisição é enviada via ajax, mas os dados não estão sendo capturados e o req.body no back-end fica como vazio. Mesmo eu criando uma string e passando para o node, o req.body continua vazio.

Form contido na view:

```html
<form method="POST" id="login">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="email" type="text" name="email" required="" placeholder="E-mail" class="input-material">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <input id="password" type="password" name="password" required="" class="input-material" placeholder="Senha">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>
```

Requisição Ajax:

```js
function autenticar(formData){
      $.ajax({
         url: '/login', 
         type: 'POST',
         data: formData,
         contentType: false,
         processData: false,           
      }).done( data => {
          console.log(data);
      }); 
}
  
$('#login').on('submit', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let form = document.getElementById('login');
  let formData =  new FormData(form);
 autenticar(formData);
});
```

Rota no Node:

```js
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
 try{
  console.log(req.body);
   const { email, password } = req.body;
   res.send({email, password});
 }
 catch (err){
  return res.status(400).send({error: 'Erro ao processar o login'});
 }
});
```

Comment: O que aparece no `console.log` do lado do node ? E o que aparece no `console.log` do lado do html ?

Comment: No lado do node aparece: { } e no lado do html aparece { } também @Isac